# Installation error in MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I accidentally removed `MySQL` from `Ubuntu 16.04`. Now when I try to install it again, error is given. Please help my out with this **error:**

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First start off with clearing your source list using:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/source.list
```

Then, type:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

check first 4 boxes, select server for (*yourcountryname*) and click revert.

Now as your problem is bit different than the reference I took, you should Try running:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
```

this will remove all related packages and dependencies for `MySQL`.

Now do:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After this try to to do fresh installation using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

This will probably fix your problem.

Reference:
[E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) [related to google chrome]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688338/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-related-to-google-chrom)

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök My Pleasure. :)

Comment: To fix the same problem I had additionally to backup `\var\lib\mysql` and `\etc\mysql` folders, perform `apt autoremove` command before installing mysql-server-5.7. And additionally stop mysql service, restore folders from the backup and start mysql service again. Without these steps your solution did not worked for me

Comment: i have followed all step mentined in solution and comments but still stuck at 
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the 

problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for providing an answer. This could potentially be a great answer if you add some additional explanation/information.